# TFLite model accuracy worse on Android

Tags: python, android, speech-recognition, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom speech recognition model which, converted to TFLite, performs excellent in python on PC. When running inference with same TFLite model on Android, accuracy drops. All the processing is happening in TFLite model layers (feature extraction, etc.) so there is no code in Android that could make a difference. Input to model is waveform and output is logits, both in python and Android. I have double checked and there is a good quality microphone input on Android, but model just performs significantly worse than on PC.

I'm having batch normalization layers in my model and I'm suspecting they might be the problem. I'm not sure why would there be inconsistency between Android and python. Did anyone else come across this problem?

Things that I ruled out:

1. Microphone - I'm using same BT headset on Android and PC
2. Model architecture - I tried two different model architectures (DeepSpeech and Jasper), both resulting in same
   accuracy degradation on Android, but they work perfect on PC
3. Quantization - my model gets quantized but it works good, without accuracy loss on PC

Comment: On the contrary...for a specific audio file that is used in python or in android, the output is exactly the same. So basically use a specific audio file in both implementations and try to debug where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give any hard and fast answers without further investigation, but
a few possible causes that come to mind:

Quantisation:
If you are comparing the network's performance before and after conversion to TFLite, then depending on your quantisation settings there is an expected drop in performance. However, if you are running the TFLite Interpreter from python as well that shouldn't be the cause. ([reference for Quantisation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization))

Domain Shift:
Just because both microphones are good quality doesn't mean that their output is the same. The compression, noise profile etc could all be different. That means your input data may be from a slightly different domain, which would then lower performance.
To test this, try saving a recording (from either device) and feeding that into the input instead. The output should be the same, if not you have some other bug.
To fix this, use recordings from the phone for your validation data when training the network (and train on some recordings from the phone too), and use recordings from the phone as your point of comparison from python.

Performance issues:
If running the network on the device is causing something to slow down, you may change the effective sample rate, even if the mic was identical. If you've fixed the domain shift error, then this is my last guess. Again it effectively causes a domain shift, but it's harder to compensate for. With this it's best to optimise your code so that it isn't causing a slowdown, or if your implementation permits it, record the sample and run the inference "offline" rather than in parallel to data collection.

Data handling bugs:
If your pipeline from the microphone to the network is different (which seems likely given its on android rather than python on the PC) then it's possible that there is a bug in how the data is getting to the network, whether that's lost packets or something that could cause a problem with normalization.

Comment: I do quantize my model, but it works perfectly in python. My dataset consists of 12 different speakers recorded on 12 different microphones. The microphone I'm using on android is BT headset, and when I connect same headset to my PC, model works good. I have also tried different model architectures (DeepSpeech and Jasper), both of them having same issue on Android, so I guess it's not about model either. The most obvious difference between Android accuracy and python is in short words like 'two', 'three', 'five'. Longer sequences like 'one-two-three-for-five' work just as good as in python.

Comment: @TomislavMedved That sounds to me like you might be clipping the data you are inputting slightly short then (perhaps missing an entry or two at the start or end). You could try recording each input to your network then see if the whole message is getting through.

Comment: that is also not the case. I've saved inputs to device storage and inspected them in audio editor. No clipping whatsoever and the levels are good. I think it might have to do with normalization (batch normalization layers or feature normalization). Besides having batch normalization layers I also normalize inputs with their individual mean and std values and that works just fine on PC but nor on Android

Comment: So did you use tf.lite.Interpreter in Python? If it works well, the model should be fine. You'd better check if the input has valid format such as Audio Format or Sampling Rate. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat

Comment: @TerryHeo yes I did. Input is fine 16khz PCM float, I have exported it to wav file and inspected in audio editor in PC and it sounds just as good as on PC.

Comment: You might want to change your program to provide wav file input and compare the output with PC version and Android version. If they're different, you could use Interpreter::PreserveAllTensorsExperimental() to compare intermediate tensors. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/interpreter_experimental.cc#L164

Comment: I didn't mean audio clipping, I meant that if your audio sequence is samples 1 -100, only samples 10 - 90 are getting to your neural network (so for longer sequences you won't notice, but for shorter ones you're missing important information)

Comment: @Stephen that is not the case, whole utterance gets in, I double checked that.

Comment: @TerryHeo that is good suggestion but I'm not sure if Java wrapper I'm using for Tensorflow on Android supports that function. At least I couldn't find the mention of it in official documentation.